# postgres import SQL inserts defer foreign key cheks for multiple files in transaction

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, foreign-keys

I have created a backup of a Postgres database consisting of several tables.
Some are referencing each other using foreign key constraints.

When trying to load the SQL insert statements in the alphabetic order of the files (i.e. not in the required order to fulfill referential integrity) obviously the load fails due to invalid foreign key constraints.

How can I global in a transaction disable all the triggers/foreign key checks (no they are default ones and not deferred ones) and happily insert the data?

I am using Postgresql 15.

Comment: Potentially: https://github.com/hasghari/table_saw might be useful

Answer (score 0):

I am now using pg_dump pg_restore. It gets the job done. I am not sure if this is the best solution.